# chromium doesn't work with orca on fedora linux

Tags: fedora, chrome, software-rec, accessibility

I want to use fedora linux on my main system with the orca screen reader, however I've ran into barriers. First of all, I like using chromium based browsers which, unlike Debian and Slackware based distros, is inaccessible with the orca screen reader.

What dependency do I need in order for the screen reader to read the output of chromium? It's accessible on Debian but I feel Fedora is the way to go, but can't use it until I know how to get chromium to work with orca. One of the reasons I don't use firefox is because of its interface on other platforms.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have at least version 3.34.1 of Orca and check whether the environment variable `ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED` is set to the value "1"?

Comment: fedora is always running the latest orca, version 40.2 but debian has it better because it has a requirement in itsrepo that makes chromium work with orca, slint-slackware also uses this same dependancy making it possible to use chromium with orca, this problem does not just affect fedora, solus and arch have this same issue, not sure about open suse since it never had orca preinstalled to start with